# how can we end this infinite loop?

Tags: python

```
def print_range(start, end):
    # Loop through the numbers from start to end
    n = start
    while n <= end:
        print(n)

print_range(1, 5)  # Should print 1 2 3 4 5 (each number on its own line)
```

Basic For Loop question. Why is it loop forever?

Comment: Hi, @younggbon. It's unclear quite what you're asking, but there are examples of using `for` loops over ranges here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Please format your post correctly before submitting it.

Answer (score 3):

You never increase `n`, therefore your code keeps on printing `1`.

Change your code to:

```
def print_range(start, end):
    # Loop through the numbers from start to end
    n = start
    while n <= end:
        print(n)
        n+=1

print_range(1, 5)  # Should print 1 2 3 4 5 (each number on its own line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop variable, `n`, is not changed within the `while` loop so it always stays equal to `start` and thus it is (likely) less than `end` forever.

Add `n = n+1` to the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You should really mark up your code. 
use ``` at the beginning and end of your code to make it a code block.

```
def print_range(start, end): 
# Loop through the numbers from start to end 
    n = start 
    while n <= end: 
        print(n)
        n += 1

print_range(1, 5) # Should print 1 2 3 4 5 (each number on its own line)
```

Comment: you can edit OP's post rather than posting as an answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Didn't know that. I'm new here and it does look like a really strange feature though.